# how to override a single automapper property mapping?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I've created a mapping from GetUsers_Result to User shown below:

```
config.CreateMap<GetUsers_Result, Core.Models.User>();
```

This works perfectly but now GetUsers_Result has a property update from UserId to UserExtensionId but this User object needs to keep its UserId property name.  Is there an easy way I can override this property mapping in the config.CreateMap() method?

Comment: Of course there is - `.ForProperty(dst => dst.UserExtensionId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserId))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
config.CreateMap<GetUsers_Result, Core.Models.User>()
    .ForProperty(dst => dst.UserExtensionId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserId))
```

Comment: While a code-only answer may provide a solution for the problem, it is better to provide an explanation on how your solution achieves this solution, and how the asker should use it.

Comment: While I take your point on board, for which I agree and normally would explain my reasoning for a particular solution to help the OP.... My coded answer is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: I agree that your code is rather self explanatory, but we should try to make questions have significance for people having the same issue in the future. In this case, I'd simply highlight on which trick you used to achieve the solution of the question, however it's obviously up to you if you do!